# jQuery on click not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question has been asked thousands of times, but I can't seem to figure out my issue. I just need another set of eyes on it to see what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="image-container">
  @foreach (var image in Model)
  {
    <a href="#" class="returnImage" data-url="@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@image.Url">
      <img src="@image.Url" id="UploadImage" data-source="@image.Url" width="200" height="200">
    </a>
  }
</div> 

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.image-container").on("click", ".returnImage", function(e) {
      var urlImage = $(this).attr("data-url");
      window.opener.updateValue("cke_72_textInput", urlImage);
      window.close();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Debugging with FireBug shows no errors and when I put a breakpoint on the "on click" function, it is never hit/never fires. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `alert` box in the function to verify if it is firing or not?

Comment: What do you except the result? I don't know what's kind of framework you're using for handlebars.

Comment: If you don't understand what is happening in your **CLIENT SIDE CODE** don't look at your **SERVER SIDE CODE**

Comment: @kojow7 Yes I have, and it is never fired.

Comment: @Ivan This project is using MVC. I just want the function to at least fire, but for some reason it's not. Even when I add an alert box in there.

Comment: I created a fiddle and it seems to work as expected.  https://jsfiddle.net/fueq8j27/

Comment: Nothing wrong with the given code snippet. May be the problem lies else where.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Thank you for the fiddle. That makes me think the problem is something else. I'm going to have to look into this a little deeper.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is the `<a>` tags are taking precedence when you click on them, suppressing the click event you have for your `div.image-container` element.

If you are intending on having the user click on the whole container itself, try using something else besides an `<a>` tag for each image in the model.

If you are intending on putting a click handler on each `<a>` tag inside your `div.image-container`, your jQuery event line should look like this instead:

```
$("div.image-container a").click(function(e) {
```

Comment: Or in the case of being super careful, you would buffer it with the .preventDefault() routine function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this does not work either. I'm think their might be a problem somewhere else in project that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".returnImage").on("click", function(e) {
  //whatever action code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where as nothing is firing, it may be that your pop-up blocker thinks your script is trying to hi-jack your browser and therefor is blocking it, especially since it is an `<a>` anchor tag wrapped in functionality that would trigger default link behavior as interpreted by the browser.  The code below is yours with a `.preventDefault()` behavior routine added, just in case that is the issue.  Edit: Updated coded to more accurately target the DOM element you want (as suggested by other answers).

[preventDefault API](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".returnImage").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var urlImage = $(this).attr("data-url");
      window.opener.updateValue("cke_72_textInput", urlImage);
      window.close();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this does not work either. I'm think their might be a problem somewhere else in project that is causing this issue. I also never knew what `preventDefault()` did, so thanks for that info!